# Will installing Ubuntu using Wubi erase Windows?

Tags: installation, dual-boot, windows-7, wubi

I have an HP laptop with 2 partitions:  `C:` and `D:`, with windows 7 installed in the `C:` drive and `D:` is the Recovery partition.

When I try to install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS using Wubi, it only shows the `C:` drive for installing and not the `D:` drive where I wanted to format and install ubuntu.

So, if I go ahead and install in the `C:` drive where windows 7 is already installed, would Wubi erase windows 7? Or it will just install Ubuntu as a program in windows?

Answer (score 2):

No, wubi runs under windows. So it won't remove the host OS.

It is like running virtual system.

Know more - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide

Comment: Not quite... It doesn't run under Windows per se, and I wouldn't (personally) call it a virtualisation either. To my knowledge it's pretty much the equivalent of a full installation, but using a virtual partition instead of a real one (so the only sense in which it "runs under Windows" is that it stores its data within a file on an NTFS filesystem, rather than needing its own drive). You're correct that it doesn't remove the host system, though.

Answer (score 0):

> or it will just install ubuntu as a program in windows??

Indeed. Wubi will install it as a program in Windows. This will make Ubuntu slower and dependent on Windows.

If you don't want to install as a program in Windows, you should [follow these instructions](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-long-term-support).